# linear trasformations $A\colon f\to \phi*f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi$ be a misurable function in [0,1] such that the linear trasformation $A\colon f\to \phi*f$ maps $L^2[0,1]$ in $L^2[0,1]$.Prove that $\phi\in L^{\infty}[0,1]$. Calculate t e norm of the operator A. When A is surjectiv,invertible,the inverse of A is continous?

Comment: It never hurts to double check that a question does not have typing errors —the absence of which do not guarantee that a question is great but helps a little... Yours has quite a few!

Comment: "Let $phi$ be a miserable function..."  :[[

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean $\cdot$ (multiplication) instead of $\ast$ (convolution)!?

The norm is of A is the essential suppremum of $|\phi|$.

For its inverse to exist and simultaneously being bounded you will need that the essential infimum $| \phi |$ is larger than zero.

If you'd really mean convolution, you could use Pontryagin duality between $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. And recycle my answer there

Comment: I mean multiplication